# Visual Studio Load Test - add_FailedToReachController message when opening test settings

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I am using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows Server 2012 and the 2012 Test Agents iso. I am trying to get the Controller and Agents configured. I have been able to get the Agent to connect to the Controller and go online. When I come to complete the configuration in visual studio I run into trouble.

If I go to LOAD TEST > Manage Test Controllers... the whole dialog is greyed out.

When I try to edit the test settings file Local.testsettings I get the error:

`"Method 'add_FailedToReachController' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.AgentProcessManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.AgentProcessManager', Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation"`

is this some kind of compatibility issue between the Controller and Visual Studio? I have them installed on the same machine.

I noticed that the Controller is 32 Bit and VS is 64 Bit, could this affect it?

Has the controller installation wiped out an assembly that VS is using?

If you could help out on this one I would be really grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to update your visual studio 2012. I installed "update 3" and it worked for me.